# PHP : foreach - Return issue (after first occurence)

Tags: php, arrays, function, return

Issue Resolved , Here is the Solution :

```
function FinalTimeTestt()
    {
        $TimeCheckArray = makeTimeCheck();

        $TBool = true;

        if(count($TimeCheckArray) >0)
        {
            foreach($TimeCheckArray as $TCA)
            {
                if($TCA['value'] != "true")
                {
                    $TBool = false;
                    return array($TBool , $TCA['courseID'] , $TCA['day']);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // do Nothing
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return array($TBool);
        }

        return array($TBool);
    }
```

I'm having a small problem with my code and its driving me crazy :

I want to go through a multi-dimensional array and if even one of its values are false , it should get out of the loop immediately and return that value - however break; doesn't seem to be working and its returning true even tho there is one occurence of "false"

$TimeCheckArray gives this :

Array ( [0] => Array ( [courseID] => comp248 [day] => monday [value] => true ) [1] => Array ( [courseID] => comp248 [day] => monday [value] => true ) [2] => Array ( [courseID] => comp345 [day] => monday [value] => false ) )

```
function FinalTimeTestt()
    {
        $TimeCheckArray = makeTimeCheck();

        if(count($TimeCheckArray) >0)
        {
            foreach($TimeCheckArray as $TCA)
            {
                if($TCA['value'] == "true")
                {
                    return array(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    return array(false , $TCA['courseID'] , $TCA['day']);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return array(true);
        }
    }
```

I'm using the function like this :

```
$hhhBool = FinalTimeTestt();

if($hhhBool[0])
{
  echo "true";
}
else
{
  echo "false";
}
```

It is returning true , even tho there is a value "false" in the array above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FinalTimeTestt()` is returning `array(true)` because it never gets past the first element in the `$TimeCheckArray` array - both branches of the if statement in the `foreach` loop return.

The first iteration looks at `Array ( [courseID] => comp248 [day] => monday [value] => true )`. The value of the `value` key is `true`, so `$TCA['value'] == "true"` evaluates to true, so `return array(true);` is executed, and the function ends there. Your use of `break` after a `return` statement suggests you don't quite understand what the latter does.

I think you want the body of your `foreach` loop to look something like this:

```
if ($TCA['value'] != 'true') {
    return array(false, $TCA['courseID'], $TCA['day']);
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks - didnt realize that , if i remove the first return - will it keep looping until it reaches a false value ?

Comment: I think the empty `else` clause and assignment to `$TBool` before returning is sloppy. I'd recommend using the 3 lines in my answer as the body instead.